# Displaying the current user name on a page in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am designing a page in sharepoint online and I want to display the current user name in text on the page.  Is there a tool that MS has built that will do this?  And if not how would one do that.

Comment: What have you tired? Are you working in Office 365 or on-prem? Is there a specific framework you want or need to work in (i.e. server-side code, client-side via CSOM or JSOM, REST API + JS/jQuery)?

Comment: Call me a simplton in this.   I am using Office 365 I am trying to stick with the WYSIWYG tools and the admin settings.  I am trying to avoid any "programming" at this point.  I am just trying to figure out how to have some text on a page that says "Welcome back [username]".  I can't imagine that I am the first person to want to do this.

Comment: Something like this would probably be the easiest then; simply copy-paste the JS into the "Source" of a Content Editor Web Part: http://sharepointthinking.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/how-to-get-the-current-login-username-using-sharepoints-jsom/

Comment: So it looks like I am moving beyond the abilities of the WYSIWYG.  Do you know any good tutorials on the JS side of sharepoint.  My next question would be why can't the WYSIWYG handle these simple queries.  I am going to working with people who can't write and use javascript.  And keeping things as clean as possible is a major priority.

Comment: For better or worse, SharePoint 2013 is all about what Microsoft calls the "App Model" of building apps with client-side tools. WYSIWYG isn't really their strategy; even their editor for SharePoint (SharePoint Designer) lost its WYSIWYG editor going from SP2010 to SP2013. If building client-side apps isn't your desire, consider the Office Store: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps-for-sharepoint-FX102804987.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using sharepoint designer. Have a look at this Blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2008/06/03/getting-the-current-user-name-or-id-in-sharepoint-using-sharepoint-designer-no-code.aspx